# i see some strange code in the window that pops up in facebook sdk at my iphone

Tags: ios4, facebook

i use this code at my post window in facebook sdk in my iphone app

```
[mainDelegate._session dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

when the windows shows up i see the following code in the words i used for my description.

```
span class text_exposed_hide ... span span class text_exposed_showspan class text_exposed_hide ... span span class text_exposed_show
```

what is this code about? should be visible to me or not?

this code is no visible when i post to facebook!!! how do i get rid of it in the window anyone?

Answer (score 0):

The code you see is so that Facebook can limit the amount of text displayed and show a More link when it's on Facebook. I don't know how to get rid of it yet, but am also experiencing it. I'll post a reply if I find out more.

Update: From what I can tell this only happens with the Description and not with the Caption. It didn't used to happen (I have apps that I haven't changed that also exhibit this behaviour) so will have to put it down to Facebook - no doubt they want us to switch to the Graph API instead (which doesn't have a preview!)